# Identical contract functions in interface with different inputs

Tags: solidity, contract-design, interfaces

In the ERC721 interface, you have two functions with the same name:

```
   function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public;
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) public;
```

Just wondering what the point of this is and why you wouldn't just want to have two different functions if the end goal is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called function overloading, where two functions have the same name but take in different arguments, you can read more about it here:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  On that though, any idea why a token transferFrom would want to include data?

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with token unfortunately but perhaps for whatever reason, there needs to be data sent with the transaction. Verification of some sort perhaps